# check string and create links if no anchor exists

Tags: php, regex

this function creates links from a string, but the problem is, if i already have a link, it doesn't work e.g: 'i am a link ', but it works with 'i am a link http://www.google.com'. any idea?

```
 function checkStringForLinks($string)
{
    /*** make sure there is an http:// on all URLs ***/
    //$string = preg_replace("/([^\w\/])(www\.[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z0-9\-]+)/i", "$1http://$2",$string);

    /*** make all URLs links ***/
    $string = preg_replace("/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i","<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</A>",$string);

    /*** make all emails hot links ***/
    //$string = preg_replace("/([\w-?&;#~=\.\/]+\@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?))/i","<A HREF=\"mailto:$1\">$1</A>",$string);

    return $string;
}
```

ooops, wrongly types. what i meant is: i dont want it to touch \anchor\link\anchor\ instead, only links that are not formed

Comment: Your regex not match with your **'i am a link '** and when you don't have a link how you are going to make it a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it right, it's not so simple, there is already free solutions for that. Like this simple class [linkify](http://brandonwamboldt.github.com/utilphp/#linkify).

```
 $string = 'some text http://www.google.com <a href="http://www.google.com">google.com</a>';Some text http://www.google.com Some text <a href="http://www.google.com">google.com</a>
 echo Util::linkify($string);
 //returns 
 //Some text <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a> Some text <a   href="http://www.google.com">google.com</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace("/([\w]+\:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i","<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</A>",$string);
```

add \ before : and you don't need () and $1,just use $0 instead